# При выборе элемента в QComboBox поля связанные с ним заполняются автоматически

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

Комбобокс заполняется из базы данных элементами. При выборе одного из элементов из списка, должны заполнятся другие поля связанные с ним. Допустим в базе данных имен, мы выбираем в комбобоксе одно имя и автоматически подтягиваются в другие лайн эдиты, типа его город проживания, номер телефона и тд. Придумала как реализовать это через наличие кнопки рядом с графой имя, но как сделать это автоматически при выборе варианта.

Answer (score 2):

У комбобокса есть сигнал **currentIndexChanged**. Он вызывается при смене значения в комбобоксе. Подключите к нему слот, где обрабатывайте логику смены значений в соответствующих виджетах (город проживания, номер телефона и тд.).

Comment: Туда нужно параметр передавать. Это и будет строка имени?

Comment: Там 2 варианта перегрузки - передаётся номер записи в комбобоксе или текущий текст.